# Top unix command ascending order

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal, top-command

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and have recently started working on bash. I need to display say memory or CPU in ascending order.

command : top

shift F, this shows window of all the column. I select n for memory and it is ordered in descending order. Same thing goes with CPU. I am unable to display these in ascending order. I have tried with shift O, O, R, shift R, P.

Comment: Why not move this to Unix.StackExchange.com?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Using `F` you'd get you to the menu of fields. Using `s` would set what field would do the sorting. Press `ESC` to escape from the menu then to change Ascending/Descending mode, use `R`.

Comment: @ konsolebox and Edourad Lopez - thank you very much for usage of R and htop installation.

Answer (score 9):

Did you have a look at other utilities ? I personally like `htop` which I found more friendly and easy to use than the traditional `top`.

## Install

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

### Run

```
htop
```

Actions are available through <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F10</kbd> keys.

## Preview

[image: Htop showing a computing load] ([cc licence](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Big-load.png))

Comment: `I` reverses the order in htop

Answer (score 6):

If you type `?` in `top`, it gives you help that tells you that `R` toggles the sort order.

Comment: with Shift+r, I can see processes related to only user, it doesn't display of root. Also, it shows all 0, 0, I cannot understand why.

Comment: Unlike `h`, this works in both BSD and GNU top